# How to retrieve column names from applying a wrapper method in feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

This question probably has a simple answer to it, so I will get to the point...

How do I retrieve the names of the columns from applying a wrapper method in feature selection?

Code I have used:

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS

X = df[['A','B','C','D']].values
y = df[['F']].values

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7) 
code = SFS(classifier,
           k_features=5, 
           forward=True, 
           floating=False, 
           verbose=8,
           scoring='accuracy'
)

code.fit(X, y)
code.k_feature_names_
```

Output:

```
Features: 3/3 -- score: 0.78

('1' '2', '3')
```

Therefore, how do I retrieve the names of the features `('1' '2', '3')`?

Comment: What is SFS?  The parameters look like the SequentialFeatureSelector from the mlxtend package, not sklearn's, which will be an important difference.

Comment: Apologies, it is the SequentialFeatureSelector from the mlxtend package

Comment: Your edit to the code didn't make much sense.  I've edited it some more, please check that it represents your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.get_support), you can get a boolean mask (in the same order) of the input features, via the **get_support method**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though, when I try this, ```AttributeError: 'SequentialFeatureSelector' object has no attribute 'get_support'```

Comment: that's because my code is not from Sebastian Raschka's mlxtend, but from a dev sklearn version; to use it, follow this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds; other option you have is to ask him via its github page if you want to use mlxtend, he is usually really nice answering your questions

Comment: Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

By using `.values` in your definition of `X`, you've converted to a numpy array and lost the column names.  Just removing that, you'll provide a frame to `SRS`, and `mlxtend` will use the column names in the `k_feature_names_` attribute; so that's probably the best approach.

There are two other approaches: one is to add the `custom_feature_names` parameter of `mlxtend.SequentialFeatureSelector` to replicate the dataframe column names, and the other is to use the `k_feature_idx_` parameter to slice a list of your columns.  Both of these require you saving the column names somewhere before casting to numpy, so the first solution is generally easier.

See the first example, and the API documentation, on the [mlxtend.SequentialFeatureSelector page](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector/#sequential-feature-selector).